# Aging report 30,60,90 above

Tags: sql-server

I try to count the no. of bills received between 30,60 and above 90 days.

Here is my T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    costcentreid,
    'Current' = CASE  
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) < 30 
                      THEN COUNT(PVNo) 
                END, 
    '30_days' = CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60  
                      THEN COUNT(PVNo) 
                END, 
    '60_days' = CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 60 AND 90 
                      THEN COUNT(PVNo) 
                END, 
    '90_plus' = CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) > 90 
                      THEN COUNT(PVNo) 
                END
FROM  
    SPRGMMS..PVRegister
GROUP BY 
    CostCentreId
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column '[DB]..PVRegister.BillDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Kindly help

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the aggregation outside

```
SELECT 
    costcentreid,
    COUNT(CASE  
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) < 30 
                      THEN PVNo
                END) as 'Current', 
    COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60  
                      THEN PVNo
                END) as '30_days', 
    COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 60 AND 90 
                      THEN PVNo 
                END) as '60_days', 
    COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate()) > 90 
                      THEN PVNo
                END) as '90_plus'
FROM  
    SPRGMMS..PVRegister
GROUP BY CostCentreId
```

Comment: @AGS careful.  You run the risk of double counting.  Between 30 and 60 and 60 and 90.   Any 60 day would be in both buckets

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.  Accepted answers reward the contributor and help others, with a similar problem, to find a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    costcentreid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '30_days'
    SUM(CASE WHEN d = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '60_days',
    SUM(CASE WHEN d = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '90_days',
FROM (
    SELECT PVNo, costcentreid, DATEDIFF(DAY, BillDate, Getdate())) / 30 AS d FROM SPRGMMS..PVRegister
) T
WHERE d <= 3
GROUP BY costcentreid
```